# How can I fix my Stripe redirectToCheckout Integration error?

Tags: typescript, next.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to run a checkout session using Stripe API. I'm able to get it integrated as i've checked my network tab in my browser's developer tools, but whenever I press the Checkout button, I run into this error.

```js
Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: stripe.redirectToCheckout: You must provide one of lineItems, items, or sessionId.
```

Here are the respective files i've used.

checkout.tsx

```js
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js"

const stripePromise = loadStripe(`My public key. This works`);

export default function Checkout() {
    const handleClick = async (event) => {
        const stripe = await stripePromise;
        const response = await fetch('/api/checkout/session', { 
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                "content-type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ quantity: 1}),
        })
        const session = await response.json();
        // When the customer clicks on the button, redirect them to Checkout.
        const result = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
          sessionId: session.id,
        });
        if (result.error) {
          // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
          // error, display the localized error message to your customer
          // using `result.error.message`.
        }
      };
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
            <button role="link" onClick={handleClick}>
                Checkout
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

session.ts

```js
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
import Stripe from 'stripe';

const stripe = new Stripe(`My secret key string. this works as well`, {
  apiVersion: '2020-08-27'
});

  export default async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  const {quantity} = req.body;
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    payment_method_types: ['card'],
    line_items: [{
      price: `My pricing key string. this works as well`,
      quantity,    
    },],
    mode: 'payment',
    success_url: `http://${req.headers.origin}/result?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
    cancel_url:  `http://${req.headers.origin}/checkout`,
  });
  res.status(200).json({ sessionId: session.id })
}
```

Comment: `.json({ sessionId: session.id })` `sessionId: session.id` Your server side is putting it in `.sessionId`, but your client side is trying to access `.id`. Change them to match

Comment: This works! Thank you so much! I was wondering why I wasn't able to access any session on my browser. I was following the doc left on the website here. 
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?ui=checkout

Comment: Where would I look to find what was written on the sever side?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your question, but  session.ts is your server side code. In the stripe tutorials, any example where you can select "nodejs" as the language is server side code.

Comment: I contemplated your answer above. I looked at the response session.ts was giving, at res.status(200).json({ sessionId: session.id }). I guess my problem was differentiating what the server is expecting from me versus what's being done on the client side.